# Bottom alignment with double-column layout

Tags: pdftex, xetex

I'm using a latex template to edit my work and encountering the following problem with **the two-column** layout.

The insertion of tables and formulae can cause the bottom of the page to be unaligned and leave a lot of extra space, as shown in

[image: this figure]

Certainly, if one page contains only text, such problem will not be encountered.

I have tried to mend this situation with `\raggedbottom` and `\flushbottom` before `\begin{document}`, but there is still no improvement.

Also, I don't want to change the original page size with a command like `\enlargethispage`.

Do you have any good suggestion?

Thanks!

**Update:**

For those who are willing to help, I will give reproductiton of the code without fine-tuning.

I'm using [Springer Latex template](https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support). Here is the reproducible code

```
\documentclass[referee, iicol, sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Reference Style

\jyear{2021}%

\raggedbottom
%\flushbottom

\begin{document}

\title[Article Title]{Article Title}

\author*[1,2]{\fnm{First} \sur{Author}}\email{iauthor@gmail.com}

\author[2,3]{\fnm{Second} \sur{Author}}\email{iiauthor@gmail.com}
\equalcont{These authors contributed equally to this work.}

\author[1,2]{\fnm{Third} \sur{Author}}\email{iiiauthor@gmail.com}
\equalcont{These authors contributed equally to this work.}

\affil*[1]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{100190}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}

\affil[2]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{10587}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}

\affil[3]{\orgdiv{Department}, \orgname{Organization}, \orgaddress{\street{Street}, \city{City}, \postcode{610101}, \state{State}, \country{Country}}}

\abstract{The abstract serves both as a general introduction to the topic and as a brief, non-technical summary of the main results and their implications. Authors are advised to check the author instructions for the journal they are submitting to for word limits and if structural elements like subheadings, citations, or equations are permitted.}

\keywords{keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3, Keyword4}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}

The Introduction section, of referenced text \cite{bib1} expands on the background of the work (some overlap with the Abstract is acceptable). The introduction should not include subheadings.

Springer Nature does not impose a strict layout as standard however authors are advised to check the individual requirements for the journal they are planning to submit to as there may be journal-level preferences. When preparing your text please also be aware that some stylistic choices are not supported in full text XML (publication version), including coloured font. These will not be replicated in the typeset article if it is accepted. 

\section{Results}\label{sec2}

This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. This is an example. \ref{tab1}

\end{document}
```

The same problem can be found in [image: this figure].

Comment: you have not shown any code so hard to offer any help. Avoiding such bad space is the reason latex floats tables, so I would guess you have prevented the table floating, but you have shown no code and not shown the relevant part of the output (top of the right hand column)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `\multicol` package. Its default setting is `flushcolumns` to ensure the last lines of the columns are aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `\raggedbottom` and keep `\flushbottom`, hope this will solve the issue